# Can I convert wait_until to wait_for using now()?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I am implementing my own `Future` class built on top of a 3rd-party waiting function `thirdPartyWait(int milliseconds)`. I want my `Future` to be interface-compatible with `std::future`, which means I'd like to provide both `wait_for` and `wait_until`.

`wait_for` is easy as it maps to `thirdPartyWait` directly (I can handle the conversion to milliseconds inside it). However, `wait_until` does not map so nicely. Intuitively, I would assume the following should do what I want:

```
template <class Clock, class Duration>
std::future_status wait_until(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> &timeout) const
{
  return wait_for(timeout - Clock::now());
}
```

I've tested the code and it works, but I am well aware a simple test does not cover all corner cases. I am not familiar enough with the `chrono` part of `std` to be sure, hence my question:

Are there any hidden pitfalls in my implementation of `wait_until`, or can I expect it to work as intended?

Comment: What happens if `Clock::rep` is unsigned and `timeout` is already in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cppreference has this to say about `std::future::wait_until`:

> The clock tied to timeout_time is used, which is not required to be a monotonic clock.There are no guarantees regarding the behavior of this function if the clock is adjusted discontinuously, but the existing implementations convert timeout_time from Clock to std::chrono::system_clock and delegate to POSIX pthread_cond_timedwait so that the wait honors ajustments to the system clock, but not to the the user-provided Clock. In any case, the function also may wait for longer than until after timeout_time has been reached due to scheduling or resource contention delays.

From which I infer that current implementations are doing exactly as you are doing.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until